# What is returned in list/interest groupings when no groups are enabled under that listid?

Tags: php, validation, mailchimp

I am able to create groups and campaigns from below link and all functions are working pretty well.

http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/interest-groupings.php.

Now I need to put some backend validation if the groups are not enabled for the particular `listid`.

```
$groups = $Mailchimp_Lists -> interestGroupings($listid,true);
print_r($groups );
// $group_count = count($groups);
```

Nothing shows here if groups are not there.

Answer (score 0):

try it this way :

```
$cnt = 0;
$groups = $Mailchimp_Lists -> interestGroupings($listid,true);
$cnt = count($groups); //count number of groups

if($cnt > 0)
{
   //matching groups found
}
else
{
   //no groups found
}
```

Comment: Hi I checked your suggestion. The if part works. It doesn't enter else part and hence no msg is returned.

Comment: you mean it is not entering `else` part even if no groups are found?

Comment: yes, it's not entering else part if no groups are there. i checked with var_dump if it is returning any null value. But nothing showed up for this particular case. if groups are there it returned the data.

Comment: mmmm....can you just `echo count($groups)` before `if` and tell me the result please?

Comment: nopes, nothing is returned if no groups. else it print out the counts.

Comment: Hi i checked with the edited code, still result is no. After that i checked with ajax request status error(ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336033/json-data-response-from-php-server-is-empty?rq=1), here i got something like Textstatus=error, error thrown=undefined, status=500.